# GridBagLayout not honoring oblong shape request

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am using swing to try to make a monopoly board. I am trying to make the properties/spaces on the board as separate JPanels that can have their own implementation, information, etc, but I am having some trouble with the shape of the spaces. I am using GridBagLayout (I am fairly new with this layout manager), and I am trying to lay the panels out so that for the side JPanels, gridwidth = 4, gridheight = 3 (see attached code). However, when I run this and look at it, the panels are square. I confirm this isn't working when I change gridheight to 2 or 1, it still shows up square (where I was expecting the JPanels to be even more oblong shaped).

Forgive the naming schemes, I am just trying this layout in a separate, temporary project file in Eclipse before I implement the gui in my main monopoly program.

```
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




    public MainFrame() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension screenSize = getToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setSize(screenSize.height, screenSize.height);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        addCorners();

        addEdges();
        setVisible(true);

        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Component resized");
                int width = getWidth();
                int height = getHeight();
                System.out.println(width + " " + height);
                super.componentResized(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private int startingColRow = 4;
    private int endingColRow = 28;

    private int bigWidth = 4;
    private int smallWidth = 3;

    private int startingEdge = 0;
    private int endingEdge = 31;




    private void addEdges() {
        addLeftEdge();
        addTopEdge();
        addBottomEdge();
        addRightEdge();
    }




    private void addCorners() {
        addTopLeftCorner();
        addBottomLeftCorner();
        addTopRightCorner();
        addBottomRightCorner();

    }




    private void addCorner(int anchor, int gridx, int gridy) {
        add(getWhiteJPanel(), getGridBagConstraints(anchor, gridx, gridy, bigWidth, bigWidth));
    }




    private void addBottomRightCorner() {
        addCorner(SOUTHEAST, endingEdge, endingEdge);
    }




    private void addTopRightCorner() {
        addCorner(NORTHWEST, endingEdge, startingEdge);
    }




    private void addBottomLeftCorner() {
        addCorner(SOUTHWEST, startingEdge, endingEdge);
    }




    private void addTopLeftCorner() {
        addCorner(NORTHEAST, startingEdge, startingEdge);
    }




    public void addLeftEdge() {
        for (int row = startingColRow; row <= endingColRow; row += smallWidth) {
            add(getWhiteJPanel(), getGridBagConstraints(WEST, startingEdge, row, bigWidth, smallWidth));
        }
    }




    public void addRightEdge() {
        for (int row = startingColRow; row <= endingColRow; row += smallWidth) {
            add(getWhiteJPanel(), getGridBagConstraints(EAST, endingEdge, row, bigWidth, smallWidth));
        }
    }




    public void addBottomEdge() {
        for (int col = startingColRow; col <= endingColRow; col += smallWidth) {
            add(getWhiteJPanel(), getGridBagConstraints(SOUTH, col, endingEdge, smallWidth, bigWidth));
        }
    }




    public void addTopEdge() {
        for (int col = startingColRow; col <= endingColRow; col += smallWidth) {
            add(getWhiteJPanel(), getGridBagConstraints(NORTH, col, startingEdge, smallWidth, bigWidth));
        }
    }




    private static JPanel getWhiteJPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        return panel;
    }




    private GridBagConstraints getGridBagConstraints(int anchor, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = VERTICAL;
        c.weightx = c.weighty = 1;

        c.anchor = anchor;
        c.gridx = gridx;
        c.gridy = gridy;
        c.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        c.gridheight = gridheight;

        return c;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example) direct in the question.  External links go stale, and most people won't follow them.

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: @Andrew: I am not sure how to make this example a MCVE. Also, I know that one line is sufficient, however I am trying to keep up with Clean Code's recommendation (the book) about making functions in as few lines as possible, and I find that adding extra space (while ugly to some) helps me pick out what are functions and what are members, inner classes, etc. I will change the formatting next time I post of SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your `c.fill = VERTICAL`, I'd have assumed `BOTH`. Apart from that, the board will have square fields if the window is square, and oblong fields if the window is oblong. Gridwidth and grigheight are completely irrelevant here. Instead you'd use these if you want to have objects whose area overlaps on one of the axes. It's best to consider a grid bag layout as a big grid. Then gridwidth and gridheight tell the layout how many columns or rows a given object should occupy. But there is nothing to say that the columns should be as wide as the rows are high. In fact there is nothing to say that the rows or columns have the same size. So I'd say you had some incorrect ideas of how GridBagLayout operates.

If you want to fix aspect ratio, you should set preferred dimensions for individual panes, and then pack the whole board into a scroll view. That will ensure that everything displays at preferred size. Not sure if scrolling is a good idea in your case, though. If not, you could try an outer container with some suitable layout which will allow the inner container to grow to its preferred size and no larger.

Comment: For the aspect ratio, specifically for a JPanel, what is the difference between setPreferredSize() and setSize()?

Comment: @ConnerPike: You call `setPreferredSize` to tell the component what size it should have. The component, when asked about its preferred size, will tell that to the layout manager, and the layout manager will compute some layout and after that call `setSize` and `setPosition`. Your code should not call `setSize` unless you are implementing a layout manager, or at least have disabled all layout managers for the container in question, since otherwise you'd interfer with that. Note that many components will give a good preferred size based on their content without a need for `setPreferredSize`.

Comment: Am I correct in making an assumption that setSize() need only be called for top level containers (JFrame, JDialog, etc)?

Comment: @ConnerPike: Yes, usually you'd only call setSize for top level windows.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use `GridBagLayout`? Maybe if you look at
the `MigLayout's` solution you will change your mind.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

/*
 * This program creates a Monopoly board using
 * the MigLayout manager.
 *
 * Author Jan Bodnar
 * Website zetcode.com
 * Last modified: July 2014
 */

public class MigLayoutMonopoly extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutMonopoly() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Monopoly");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, gap 2 2"));

        // top row of panels
        add(createPanel2());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel2(), "wrap");

        // left column of panels
        add(createPanel3(), "wrap");
        add(createPanel3(), "wrap");
        add(createPanel3(), "wrap");
        add(createPanel3(), "wrap");
        add(createPanel3(), "wrap");
        add(createPanel3(), "wrap");
        add(createPanel3(), "wrap");
        add(createPanel3(), "wrap");
        add(createPanel3(), "wrap");
        add(createPanel2());

        // bottom row of panels
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel1());
        add(createPanel2());

        // right column of panels
        add(createPanel3(), "cell 10 1");
        add(createPanel3(), "cell 10 2");
        add(createPanel3(), "cell 10 3");
        add(createPanel3(), "cell 10 4");
        add(createPanel3(), "cell 10 5");
        add(createPanel3(), "cell 10 6");
        add(createPanel3(), "cell 10 7");
        add(createPanel3(), "cell 10 8");
        add(createPanel3(), "cell 10 9");

        // center panel
        add(createPanel2(), "cell 1 1 9 9, grow");

        pack();
    }

   public JPanel createPanel1() {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(){ 

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(40, 60);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }            

        };

        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        return pnl;
    }    

   public JPanel createPanel2() {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(){ 

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(60, 60);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }                  

        };

        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        return pnl;
    }   

   public JPanel createPanel3() {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(){ 

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(60, 40);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }                  

        };

        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        return pnl;
    }      


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutMonopoly ex = new MigLayoutMonopoly();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`MigLayout` has a powerful grid structure where we can place components relatively
or using absolute cell indeces.

It depends on the requirements but I assume that the board panels should not shrink 
because they are to contain bitmaps. (Maybe the container should have fixed size.) Therefore, I have set the preferred sizes of the panels equal to minimim sizes -- the panels do not shrink but are cut from the panel. Also when the container grows, the panels do not
grow but the gaps between the panels. All this can be set to one's needs.

[image: Monopoly board]